# How does browser know which KDC to contact in kerberos?

Tags: kerberos, spnego, spring-security-kerberos, mit-kerberos

I am new to Kerberos and I am not sure how browser knows which KDC to contact for ticket for a HTTP service?

For example, I have an application (SPNEGO) running on [www.xyz.example.com](http://www.xyz.example.com) and my realm is example.com ( I have a linux server as KDC server), what will be the SPN created and how will browser contact KDC?

Answer (score 1):

> how browser knows which KDC to contact for ticket for a HTTP service?

The browser never directly contacts the KDC. Instead, it relies on the ticket cache maintained by the operating system. If the ticket for the specified service is not found in cache, then OS connects with the KDC and puts the new ticket in cache, from where the browser can pick it up.

> what will be the SPN created and how will browser contact KDC?

General format of the SPN is `<service class>/<host>:<port>/<service name>`. If you have a web application running on `xyz.example.com`, then usually (not necessarily) the format of your SPN will be `HTTP/xyz.example.com`

SPNs are not defined automatically. Administrator has to register the SPNs at the time the keytab is generated.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer @Bhushan. If I install kerberos (krb5-admin-server) on a linux server and try to access an application running on the same machine on a windows server? Will this be a possible use case?

Comment: Where your AD is? ideally that os should be your KDC

Comment: Say, KDC setup is done in linux without AD (https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-setup-kerberos-server-and-client-on-ubuntu-1804-lts/) . Will this work for HTTP services authentication?

Comment: That should be possible. Have you checked https://serverfault.com/questions/818138/set-up-a-windows-10-client-for-a-linux-kdc-realm this thread?

Comment: Yes I have checked this URL. By this approach I get the error "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: GSSContext name of the context initiator is null" and I am not able to find a solution for it. Hence, I wanted to ask if it is a possible scenario.

Comment: such setups are rare and not much documentation is available. In most of the cases, issues are related to config and nothing about the actual app. only way is to debug it - check the log statements in details. check if your server sends negotiate, browser  gets the ticket from cache, and then sends it to the server, intercept the request to check if the token is passed  - you can use wireshark to monitor network traffic.